# How to read app specific log from android device

Tags: android, logging

I have developed an app which runs in the background and it writes some logs with lots of exception, verbose, crash results etc.
Now I want to read those app logs from my mobile after a few days of running for testing purposes.

How can I read that log?
Where it is saved?

Comment: The log buffer is a limited amount of memory, so once full, new messages start pushing out old ones.  Depending on the size and how noisy the installed software is, that could be in a few minutes or the better part of a day, but it is unlikely to cover "a few days"

Comment: so where the log is save ? how to read that?

Comment: @Abhijit is it possible to read other app logs with package name from one app? both apps are my own

Answer (score 0):

You can manually use logging tools and then write it to a text file and then read.
check [microlog4android](https://code.google.com/p/microlog4android/) and [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) and similar libraries.